# Can SSRS 2014 and SSRS 2016 operate concurrently in the Visual Studio development environment

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014, ssrs-2016

I have developed and trialled a number of reports on my laptop using SQL Server 2014 and SSRS 2014 running in a VS 2013 Community Edition IDE. Can I install SQL Server 2016 and the 2016 SSDTs and run SSRS 2016 without removing SSRS 2014?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install SQL Server and SSRS 2016, and keep the 2014 versions on your machine. Just make sure to install the 2016 versions under a different named instance than what the 2014 version is using. They will not interfere with each other.

The latest SSDT can be used to develop reports in either version of SSRS.

Comment: Many thanks.  Exactly the information I was looking for>